# How can I implement Lightning Web Components into my React application?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, integration, react

I have created a simple LWC that displays a form and sends user data to Salesforce:

`userForm.js`

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class UserForm extends LightningElement {
    objectApiName = 'Contact';
    fieldList = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email'];
}
```

`userForm.html`

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title='Contact Creation'>
        <p class='slds-p-horizontal_small'>
            <lightning-record-form 
                object-api-name={objectApiName} 
                fields={fieldList}>
            </lightning-record-form>
        </p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

I am trying to work out how I can implement this so that I can render this form in my react project.

I have created a `rollup.config.js` file at root level:

```
import lwc from "@lwc/rollup-plugin";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";

export default {
    input: "src/index.js",
    output: {
        file: "dist/index.js",
        format: "esm",
    },
    plugins: [
        replace({
            "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development"),
        }),
        lwc(),
    ],
};
```

as well as an `lwc.config.json` file:

```
{
    "modules": [
        {
            "dir": "src/modules"
        }
    ]
}
```

and have the following dependencies installed in my `node_modules`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@lwc/rollup-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^2.4.2",
    "lwc": "^2.1.0",
    "rollup": "^2.50.5"
},
```

Both my `userForm.js` and `userForm.html` files are contained within the src folder of my react project. My plan was to import `userForm.js` directly into the component I want it to be displayed in, `ValidateUser.js`, and simply reference it in the return statement:

`ValidateUser.js`

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import UserForm from '../path to userForm.js'

class ValidateUser extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <UserForm  />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

However this does not work and in the console I receive the error:

`Warning: The <UserForm /> component appears to have a render method, but doesn't extend React.Component. This is likely to cause errors. Change UserForm to extend React.Component instead.`

Does anybody know of a way that this can be achieved?

Comment: why don't you just create a react form component? what is the benefit of this approach?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. My end goal here is just to find a way to include a form in my project that submits data to Salesforce. I'm using lwcs but open to using any other approach that will help me achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any advantage on trying to use a LWC in a react app, you just need an HTML form (can be built using react), you can leverage the [UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm)  to send your form data to Salesforce without the need of trying what you seem to be asking.

Comment: Yes, on researching the UI API this definitely seems like the right way to go. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: no prob =) - glad I was able to help